# PIG: How to create percentage (%) based table?

Tags: apache-pig

I am trying to create a table that will show the number of occurrence in percentage. For example: I have a table, named as *example* that contains data as:

```
class, value
------ -------
1     ,  abc
1     ,  abc
1     ,  xyz
1     ,  abc
2     ,  xyz
2     ,  abc
```

Here, for the class value 1, 'abc' occurred 3 times and 'xyz' occurred only once out of total occurrence of 4 times. For class value 2, 'abc' and 'xyz' occurred once (out of total two times occurrence).

So, the output is:

```
class, %_of_abc, %_of_xyz
------ --------  --------
1     ,  75     ,   25
2     ,  50     ,   50
```

Any idea how to do it where both the column values are changing? I was thinking to do it using *GROUP*. But not sure if I group it by class value, how it could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

little bit complex, but here the solution

```
grunt> Dump A;
(1,abc)
(1,abc)
(1,xyz)
(1,abc)
(2,xyz)
(2,abc)
grunt> B = Group A by class;
grunt> C = foreach B generate group as class:int, COUNT(A) as cnt;
grunt> D = Group A by (class,value);          
grunt> E = foreach D generate FLATTEN(group), COUNT(A) as tot_cnt;
grunt> F = foreach E generate $0 as class:int, $1 as value:chararray, tot_cnt;
grunt> G = JOIN F BY class,C BY class;
grunt> H = foreach G generate $0 as class,$1 as value,($2*100/$4) as perc;
grunt> Dump H;
(1,xyz,25)
(1,abc,75)
(2,xyz,50)
(2,abc,50)
I = grouy H by class;
J = FOREACH I generate group as class, FLATTEN(BagToTuple(H.perc));
Dump J;
(1,75,25)
(2,50,50)
```

Comment: Thanks! Working perfectly!